# Usar argumentos numa função provenientes de outra função

Tags: python, funções, argumento

Eu tenho um documento de texto com o seguinte formato:

```
word_1 word_2 word_3
word_4 word_5 word_6
```

Para cada linha desse documento de texto:

- primeiro: quero salvar as palavras e adicionar "_info" a cada palavra;
- segundo: os argumentos que eu quero usar na próxima função (que se repete para cada linha) são:

  ```
  def my_function 
  ("word_1","word_2","word_3","word_1_info","word_2_info","word_3_info")
  ```

Após os primeiros cálculos com os argumentos da primeira linha, os argumentos seguintes serão:

```
def my_function ("word_4","word_5","word_6","word_4_info","word_5_info","word_6_info")
```

O mais próximo que estive foi ler (porque estou tendo problemas para adicionar "_info" a cada palavra), as informações do arquivo de texto da seguinte forma:

```
f = open("test.txt","r")
array=[]

for line in f:
    x = re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z]+_+\d",line)
    array.append(x)


def my_function("array[0][0]","array[0][1]","array[0][2]")
```

Como posso melhorar meu código para fazer o que preciso?

Answer (score 0):

Ola, tentarei te ajudar :)

Para o python esse "array=[ ]" na verdade é uma lista

**>>> type([])**  ===:> class list

Ao indicar um arquivo pode  passar direto para um loop.

Imagino eu que este arquivo internamente estaria assim:

word_4

word_5

word_6

word_4

word_5

nova_lista = list()

for linhas in open("test.txt"):

#linhas  ....  Ocorrera a leitura do txt mas no entanto havera uma \n

linhas.strip() # desta maneira nao ocorrera uma linha vazia

ref = f'{linhas.strip()}_info' # usando f string

nova_lista.append(ref) # adiciona a lista

Se neste arquivo houver mais que 10 conteudo.

Vai escrever todos ?

Poderia usar um descompactador

def my_function (*nova_lista)

loop.....

Caso realmente quer acessar cada um pela função

def my_function (exem1, exem2, exem3, exem4 ,exem5)

print(exem1)

print(exem2)

Só chamar a função passando a lista

my_function(*nova_lista)